# BUG - SPARQL Describe query returns nothing in Anzograph

Tags: sparql, anzograph

The SPARQL Describe query does not do anything in Anzograph 2.2.0. I have also double checked the documentation at https://docs.cambridgesemantics.com/anzograph/v2.2/userdoc/describe.htm and the simple example fails to return triples.

To reproduce, let's insert some data.

```
INSERT DATA {
  graph <tickit> {
     <person2> <lastname> "Humphrey" ;
        <like> <musicals> .
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Update Successful
```

SPARQL Select queries work as expected.

```
SELECT *
FROM <tickit>
WHERE {
 ?s ?p ?o . 
} LIMIT 10
```

Output:

```
+-----------+------------+------------+
| <person2> | <lastname> | Humphrey   |
| <person2> | <like>     | <musicals> |
+-----------+------------+------------+
```

Now if I try to use a SPARQL Describe query, nothing happens.

```
DESCRIBE <person2>
FROM <tickit>
```

Output:

```
No records found.
```

I've also enabled the `sparql_spec_default_graph` in `settings.conf`. Therefore, I'd expect to get something by running the following SPARQL Describe query on the default graph.

```
DESCRIBE <person2>
```

Output:

```
No records found.
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have hit a bug in the way the AnzoGraph web console processes the DESCRIBE query results. This has now been ticketed and will be addressed in an upcoming release - probably 2.2.1 (the next one). The AnzoGraph CLI does handle DESCRIBE correctly.

Many thanks indeed for the report!